# Como puedo tomar el valor que tiene un DropdownMenuItem

Tags: formularios, flutter

no me selecciona nada a pesar de que me muestra la lista de elementos a seleccionar

```dart
 Expanded(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      items: <String>["Femenino", "Masculino", "Otro"]
                          .map((i) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: i,
                        child: Text(i),
                      ))
                          .toList(),
                      hint: OrdenSelec == ""
                          ? Text(
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                          "Seleccionar sexo")
                          : Text(style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17), OrdenSelec),
                      onChanged: (value) => {
                        setState(() {
                          OrdenSelec = value.toString();
                        })
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

El widget `DropDownButton` tiene el atributo `value`, que recibe el valor actual del widget. Si el valor, cambia, este atributo debe cambiar. En tu onChange, estás modificando la variable `OrdenSelect`, pero no la variable `i`, la cual estás usando para asignar el valor al `DropDownButton`.

Tienes dos opciones. Puedes usar `OrdenSelect` para asignar el valor al widget. En ese caso, reemplazas `i` por `OrdenSelect` o en el onChange actualizas el valor de `i`. Te aconsejaría usar una única variable para todo.

Como consejo adicional, cuando tengas que usar un Widget de Flutter y no sepas bien cómo funciona, te recomendaría leer la documentación de dicho Widget. Afortunadamente, Flutter cuenta con una de las documentaciones más extensas y bien redactadas que hay, para mi gusto.

Aquí tienes el link de la documentación del widget en cuestión:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

También te dejo el exemplo que viene en la doc, para acortarte esfuerzos.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const List<String> list = <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];

void main() => runApp(const DropdownButtonApp());

class DropdownButtonApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DropdownButtonApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('DropdownButton Sample')),
        body: const Center(
          child: DropdownButtonExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DropdownButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropdownButtonExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<DropdownButtonExample> createState() => _DropdownButtonExampleState();
}

class _DropdownButtonExampleState extends State<DropdownButtonExample> {
  String dropdownValue = list.first;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        // This is called when the user selects an item.
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = value!;
        });
      },
      items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```